# ls -l seems to give one concatenation of the filenames found in a directory

Tags: shell, files, ls, quoting, wildcards

I want to write a shellscript to convert all .ogg files in a directory to .mp3 files.
The filenames contain spaces, so I use a lot of double quotes in the sequenco of commands. The command I use is

```
for FILE in "`ls -1 *.ogg`" ; do
    ROOTFILE=`printf "%s\n" "$FILE" | sed "s/ogg//" `
    ffmpeg -i "$FILE" "$ROOTFILE"mp3
done
```

But the all the filenames in the directory are now seen by ffmpeg as one string. How can I separate the individual filenames, while preserving the spaces in them?

Answer (score 1):

Summarising all the comments (written by [Eric Renouf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/109842/eric-renouf), [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver), and [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas)), the solution to your problem is

```
for f in *.ogg; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.ogg}.mp3"
done
```

This avoids a couple of issues with your attempt:

- [parsing `ls`’s output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440);
- re-inventing `basename` (which itself can usually be replaced with shell string processing, as above).